# gradient line using css background - not working in ie 7 and 8

Tags: linear-gradients, css

I have come up with the following css which creates a 100% x 1 high line - basically a replica hr with styling.  The ends fade into a grey color to the center.  Works perfectly fine on latest chrome, ff, opera, ie10 and ie9.  It shows nothing at all for ie7 and ie8.  What the heck am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]> <html class="ie8" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie9" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

and just using "" to show the line.

```
.g-line{
height:1px;
width:100%;
display:block;
background: rgb(222,222,222); /* Old browsers */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(222,222,222,1) 15%, rgba(222,222,222,1) 85%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(15%,rgba(222,222,222,1)), color-stop(85%,rgba(222,222,222,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 15%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 85%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 15%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 85%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 15%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 85%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 15%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 85%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

.ie9 .g-line{
filter:none;
}
```

Comment: What's your HTML? if `.ie9 .g-line` applies, then the `filter: none` will override the filter for the gradient

Comment: just using <div class="g-line"></div>... that filter only applies to ie9 and nothing else.

Comment: edited op to show so there is no confusion about the filter call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at this quite a few ways and have come to this conclusion... for ie7 and ie8 I will use :

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
  startColorstr='#00dedede',
  endColorstr='#dedede',
  GradientType=1
);
```

and

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
  startColorstr='#dedede',
  endColorstr='#00dedede',
  GradientType=1
);
```

The `00` represents `0` `opacity` level.  Of course, with this method I will have to make left and right lines and combine them, so one extra `div` then currently and some extra css for the additional side, but this will take care of all browsers and look the same as it does now.

Answer (score 0):

`background: rgb(222,222,222);` is invalid in IE7-8. Use the HEX equivalent `#DEDEDE`.

Comment: It makes no difference if I use background: rgb(222,222,222); or background:#DEDEDE; - still nothing shows in those two browsers.

Comment: What if you move the IE6-8 filter to `.ie8 .g-line`?

Comment: Well if you do that then you are removing filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */

Comment: Removing it from `.g-line`, yes. Moving it under `.ie8 .g-line`, which is covered by `<!--[if lte IE 8 ]>`

Comment: I see what you are saying, but that line is specifically for ie6-8 and nothing else.  So removing it does not make sense.  I did find that if I change the color values from 00ffffff to something like 000000 and 888888 it works.  I was under the assumption '00ffffff' was the correct syntax for the transparency with IE.  No?

Answer (score 0):

ie7 doesn't support data uris. ie8 does with a few distinctions, the largest being they can't be > 32kb. docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(VS.85).aspx you'll have to implement mhtml to get data uris working in ie7. you can read more about it and see a demo here: http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-data-uris-in-all-browsers
but offhand, a super easy way for you to achieve this would be to serve up a png or gif for ie8 and below. you're already serving up < IE8 styles, if you changed that to less than or equal to, you could simply replace the background style for that class, like so:

```
.ie8andbelow .g-line{background:url("image-for-ie8-and-below.png")}
```